# Can my ps3 play ps2 discs?

Tags: ps3, ps2

I was thinking about getting some ps2 discs and wanted to know if my system can handle them? It's a Rigel or somesuch according to Netflix.

Thanks

Comment: There is previous discussion on this topic [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62563/is-the-slim-ps3-capable-of-playing-ps1-and-ps2-games) and [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17859/why-is-it-so-difficult-to-emulate-ps2-games-in-a-ps3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 40GB, 80GB re-release, 160GB, and the slim version of the PS3 are not officially backwards compatible with PS2 games because all hardware chips from the former console are omitted and there is no software emulation; however, a chipped method is available.

Comment: What does "a chipped method" mean?

Answer (score 0):

The last one, so far as I know that was backward compatible out of the box was the one that came bundl d with metal gear solid 4. I play my ps2 games on it at least weekly.